# How to display image in another activity/fragment from circle image view with on click method in android studio(java)?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have some images in my circle image view. I want to display every single image in new image view with on click method. Can some help?

Comment: please provide some of your code, where you stuck, so we can help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide us some more details about what you have tried so far, source code etc.

Comment: Here is my circle image view:
circleImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_id);
        circleImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 //code for displaying single image view when I click on circle image view
            }
        });